# Can you use 丰富 to describe a day?

Tags: grammar

So, I'm trying to figure out how to use 丰富 most correctly. I know that youcan say 今天的晚餐很丰富。  But how else could it be used? Could I say “今天过得好丰富？“ in say a written diary?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Yes, you can. I would opt for 充实 instead of 丰富 here though.

Comment: @user3306356 `充实 (meaningful)` fits this sentence structure better but it doesn't have the same meaning as `丰富 (plentiful)`. To preserve that meaning I'd prefer `今天的*活动*很丰富`.

Comment: @NS.X I'm guessing from the 'idea' of the sentence, that OP is using `丰富` where `充实` should be used...English though process...just a guess!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

丰富的一天 - an eventful day with plenty activities but you may not get anything positive out of them.

充实的一天 - perhaps not as many activities as in 丰富的一天 but you actually get something positive from part-taking in the day's activities.

It does sound a bit odd to say “今天过得好丰富？“. Perhaps "今天是丰富的一天" sounds better.

Answer (score 4):

you're definitely right. But in my opinion 丰富 and 充实 they both mean `many`. 
（今天过的好丰富 because you have many different kinds of things to do but not all of them are meaningful, maybe just some of them. However, you have a busy day!)

And 今天晚餐很丰富 just means today's dinner is plentiful not meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

充实is ok.
eg:今天过得真充实 or 今天真是充实的一天

Comment: Would this mean that it was "good" day? Or simply that a lot happened?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.丰富Should be used for something or some event, but not a day. It will be sounds strange for Chinese.